# Should we dissolve the smart-contracts tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

We have:

- [contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-design)
- [contract-development](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-development)
- [contract-debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-debugging)
- [contract-invocation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-invocation)

Do we still need a [smart-contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-contracts) tag? (Y/n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets nuke it. The tags contract-design, contract-development, contract-invocation and contract-debugging should jointly cover most usage.

**Update** All uses of the smart-contracts tag are retagged. Now we need to figure out what to do with the [contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) synonym and [smart-contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-contracts) itself.

Comment: Wow you are fast! Good job. unused tags will disappear after 24 hours as far as I know.