# Should we blacklist the smart-contracts tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, blacklist-request

In 
[Should we dissolve the smart-contracts tag?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/should-we-dissolve-the-smart-contracts-tag) Joris did excellent work to [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate) the smart-contracts tag:

> The tags contract-design, contract-development, contract-invocation
>   and contract-debugging should jointly cover most usage.
>
> All uses of the smart-contracts tag are retagged. Now we need
>   to figure out what to do with the contracts synonym and
>   smart-contracts itself.

He was able to retag everything appropriately, and everyone benefits from a more precise tag.

Should we put in a request to blacklist the smart-contracts tag ?  [How should we make tag blacklist requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests)

Comment: From the link you posted: _There are a lot of burninate-requests posted to various meta sites that are... To put it gently... A complete and utter waste of everyone's time._ :-P

Comment: @5chdn We actually burninated already in the past, so need to do step2, 3... of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests

Comment: Ok, we are in step #3 then. So let's use this thread to re-evaluate why the tag should be disallowed. And if there is consensus.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect we are in step3.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is too generic, and all the technical aspects are well covered by the other tags. So I can see why this one should be buried.