# Should we blacklist the contracts tag?

Tags: discussion, support, blacklist-request

[contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) is a synonym for the smart-contracts tag.

We have the following discussion:
[Should we blacklist the smart-contracts tag?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281/should-we-burninate-the-smart-contracts-tag)

> The tags contract-design, contract-development, contract-invocation
>   and contract-debugging should jointly cover most usage.
>
> All uses of the smart-contracts tag are retagged. Now we need to
>   figure out what to do with the contracts synonym and smart-contracts
>   itself.

If we decide we'd like to do the same for [contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts), the process is we need this separate question for it.

Comment: maybe we should compile a list of tags that should be blacklisted.

Comment: @5chdn sure we can do that; later we'll need a separate request for each one since that's what the admins (right term?) prefer.

Comment: Not sure what the recommended way is, but I just thought about which additional tags should be blacklisted and there are not really any others coming to my mind right now, so one per question is just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes somehow this is like asking if a vegetarian would eat chicken instead of turkey. No brainer, dig the hole.