# Which tags should we consider blacklisting?

Tags: discussion

[Good Tags now save a lot of work later!](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/good-tags-now-save-a-lot-of-work-later/) and [@5chdn suggested](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/should-we-blacklist-the-contracts-tag#comment298_282) we think of which tags should be blacklisted, since some of them just aren't helpful.

Which ones should we consider blacklisting?  Let's collect them here as we (re)discover them.

Answer (score 2):

[data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) - is so generic.  When appropriate, we have [calldata](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calldata).

[api](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) - similarly generic

[best-practice](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice) - it's a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags)

Comment: Maybe we are missing our target with this thread. `data` might be a good tag since there is a specific application for it, if we use it for the data field in transactions or contract data. maybe all it needs is a good wiki. Both tags have less than 20 questions. Is blacklisting really needed?

Comment: For the relevant ones, I retag with [tag:calldata].  If [tag:data] wasn't an option, people would find [tag:calldata] which has a description, easier.  Contract data is usually [tag:storage] but may be good to revisit too.

Answer (score 1):

I got one for you:

- [blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blockchain), 143 questions! This one goes on one line with [ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereum) and [contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) regarding beeing too generic and very close to the site's scope.

Comment: When we review it, let's see how we can improve some of the tagging to be more precise, or if it just shouldn't be on a question.  I upvoted but not sure if we needed multiple wikis ;)