# Should we dissolve the dapps tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm a bit confused, because I was 110% sure we already dissolved the [dapps](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapps) tag. But there are 100+ questions tagged with dapps and I recommend [we proceed like we did](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/173/87) with the [smart-contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-contracts) tag.

We have:

- [dapp-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapp-design)
- [dapp-development](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapp-development)
- [dapp-debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapp-debugging)

Do we still need a [dapps](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapps) tag? (Y/n)

Answer (score 3):

**n**

It's like if stackoverflow had a "program" tag. Nearly every question will relate to a dapp in some way. I'm not sure what exactly you would learn from browsing the tag, or what you would put in the tag wiki, etc.